# PHP IDE with webservice wsdl Import Support

Tags: php, ide, wsdl, class

Recently I have been building a lot of applications that needs to access webservices. I currently use a tool wsdl2php to generate a php Class file from the wsdl file.

I was wondering if there are IDE's available that can do the same thing, or at least make it really easy to access/code against the Methods that are available.

I currently use Nusphere PHPed as IDE, but they only support this with their own NUSOAP client.

When you guys need to access a Webservice from PHP which IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to create a SOAP Client from WSDL then see [this page](http://devzone.zend.com/article/689) 
More specifically check Example 2.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. The example is a real simple one. Most Web-services work with a lot of Objects, I would like an IDE that is able to create these classes. To easily communicate with the web service

Answer (score 0):

Kevin have you tried using the wsdl2php tool?

http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/

Then most PHP IDEs will use a wrapper helper type option once you use include() or require_once();

Comment: Thanks Claw, but I was already familiar with this tool. I was hoping to find a IDE that could do the same thing as this tool.

Comment: If you find one. Please post :)

Comment: have you looked at any of the Altova XML stuff?